# JPEG category encode bitwise operation

Tags: c, jpeg

In the Cryx [note](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/formats/jpeg.txt) about JPEG compression, categories are described as "the minimum size in bits in which we can keep that value". It goes on to say that values falling within certain ranges are put into categories. I have pasted a segment below but not the whole table.

```
     Values             Category        Bits for the value

    0                   0                   -

      -1,1                  1                  0,1

   -3,-2,2,3                2              00,01,10,11

 -7,-6,-5,-4,4,5,6,7            3    000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111
```

The JPEG encoder/decoder found [here](https://github.com/rockcarry/ffjpeg) performs the category encoding with a bitwise operation that I don't understand and I am hoping someone can clarify for me. RLE of 0's is done elsewhere, but this portion of the code breaks up the remaining pixel values into the categories as specified in the Cryx document.

In the code below, the variable `code` is the value of the YUV value of the pixel. In the while loop, if the conditions are met, `i` is decremented until the correct category is reached. For example, if the pixel value is 6.0, starting from category 15, `i` is decremented until 3 is reached. This is done with a bitwise operation that I do not understand. Can someone please clarify what condition is being tested for in the while loop? More specifically, `!(absc & mask)` is a Boolean, but I don't understand how this helps us to know the correct category.

The reason for the last if statement is also unclear to me. Thanks

```
    unsigned absc = abs(*code);
    unsigned mask = (1 << 15);
    int i    = 15;
    if (absc == 0) { *size = 0; return; }
    while (i && !(absc & mask)) { mask >>= 1; i--; }
    *size = i + 1;
    if (*code < 0) *code = (1 << *size) - absc - 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while` here is used to find the most significant bit in `code`. Or in other words - length of `code` in bits.

The loop consequently applies mask to get next bit in `code`. First, mask is `1000000000000000` in binary form with `1` in 15th bit (zero based), the most valued bit in 2-byte (16 bit) number. Operator `&` (binary AND) zeros all bits in `absc` except one with 1 in mask. If result is zero than shift mask right (remove last binary digit) and repeat with next bit.

For value 6 = `110`b (binary form) `while` will work till mask = `100`b and i = 2. After it `size` will be set to 3.

If `code` was negative than the last line will convert it in [one’s compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) representation with `size` length. Such encoding of negative numbers is described in your categories list.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's a great answer. Can you elaborate a little more about how right bit shift is used to find the correct category?

Comment: @m_ridge Right shift operator `>>= 1` moves all bits by one bit position to "the right" - to the least significant bits. More information with pictures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift. For example, `1000`b after right shift by one bit position will transform into `100`b. In our case mask will change on every loop step and test next bit position for 1 in it. When 1 is found - we exit loop

Comment: Please, feel free to upvote answers if they are helpful. You can do it even on accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks but how does finding where the most significant bit is help us determine the category?

Comment: Oh, I think I see. For example if 31 is ```11111```b and mask is ```100000```, ```i``` will be decremented and then ```mask``` becomes ```10000```, and at that point the ```&``` will then show have a 1 at the right most bit, i.e.   ```!(absc & mask)``` = 1 and the ```while``` stops

Comment: @m_ridge Correct. `i` will be 4 when loop stops in your example and `size` = i + 1 = 5

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated!